# Comparison of Diagonal Data

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Mine demo table is as shown

```
     a   b
    DXB BAH
    BAH DXB
    DEL BAH
    BAH BOM
```

I want o/p as DXB-BAH-DXB-DEL-BAH-BOM.

Any suggestions on how to get the desired o/p???

Comment: Do you have any column to define the sort order of the rows? Rows in a relational database have not sort order, so you have to specify a column to sort the rows in order to the order you want.

Comment: It should always start from the first column of the table & then can compare diagonally.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first row" - unless you have an order by.

Comment: If u mean which column should be present in 'order by ' clause ,then the column will be 'a' for above example

Comment: If you order by `A` then you won't get the order you have shown us (because `DXB` comes _after_ `BAH`)

Comment: Taking eg of above, A got 4 values as A1-DXB,A2 -BAH & so on....
Same for B as B1-BAH,B2-DXB...
If B1 values is same as A2 ,then only 1 entry must be obtained else both the values of B1 followed by A2 & so on upto last record of column B.